# How to display just the weekdays on x-axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to plot a scatter-connected graph using D3.js. The graph uses JSON as input to show the people count for different shifts on different dates of January 2020. Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Line Chart</title>
 <style>
   svg {
    font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}
.line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path {
  stroke: black;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title-text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<!-- partial -->
  <script>

var data = [
  {
    name: "Regular",
    values: [
      {date: "2020-01-01", count: "2"},
      {date: "2020-01-02", count: "4"},
      {date: "2020-01-03", count: "8"},
      {date: "2020-01-04", count: "3"},
      {date: "2020-01-05", count: "5"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Shift1",
    values: [
      {date: "2020-01-01", count: "2"},
      {date: "2020-01-02", count: "4"},
      {date: "2020-01-03", count: "8"},
      {date: "2020-01-04", count: "6"},
      {date: "2020-01-05", count: "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Shift2",
    values: [
      {date: "2020-01-01", count: "3"},
      {date: "2020-01-02", count: "8"},
      {date: "2020-01-03", count: "4"},
      {date: "2020-01-04", count: "7"},
      {date: "2020-01-05", count: "6"}
    ]
  }
];

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 50;
var duration = 250;

var lineOpacity = "0.25";
var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
var lineStroke = "1.5px";
var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

var circleOpacity = '0.85';
var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
var circleRadius = 3;
var circleRadiusHover = 6;


/* Format Data */

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%a");
data.forEach(function(d) { 
  d.values.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.count = +d.count;    
  });
});

/* Scale */
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width-margin]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.count)])
  .range([height-margin, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
  .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


/* Add line into SVG */
var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.date))
  .y(d => yScale(d.count));

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'line-group')  
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .style("fill", color(i))        
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
        .attr("y", 5);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
    })
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')  
  .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
  .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
  .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll('.line')
                    .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
      d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
                    .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
        .style("cursor", "none");
    });


/* Add circles in the line */
lines.selectAll("circle-group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d => d.values).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle")  
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .text(`${d.count}`)
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.count) - 10);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .selectAll(".text").remove();
    })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.count))
  .attr("r", circleRadius)
  .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this) 
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadius);  
      });


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(7);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(7);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .text("Total values");
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am clueless on how to get only weekdays on x-axis like Mon, Tue, etc without having the month displayed inbetween.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add `.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a"))` after `xAxis` var declaration.

Example https://codepen.io/nufrankz/pen/VwabXzJ

EDIT:
`%a` for short weekday, `%A` for full weekday. Full list [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `tickFormat` function passing the desired `timeFormat` e.g

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a"))
            .ticks(7);
```

Working example (may not be exactly what you want but should show you how to control the axis labels.

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "Regular",
    values: [
      {date: "2020-01-01", count: "2"},
      {date: "2020-01-02", count: "4"},
      {date: "2020-01-03", count: "8"},
      {date: "2020-01-04", count: "3"},
      {date: "2020-01-05", count: "5"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Shift1",
    values: [
      {date: "2020-01-01", count: "2"},
      {date: "2020-01-02", count: "4"},
      {date: "2020-01-03", count: "8"},
      {date: "2020-01-04", count: "6"},
      {date: "2020-01-05", count: "1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Shift2",
    values: [
      {date: "2020-01-01", count: "3"},
      {date: "2020-01-02", count: "8"},
      {date: "2020-01-03", count: "4"},
      {date: "2020-01-04", count: "7"},
      {date: "2020-01-05", count: "6"}
    ]
  }
];

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 50;
var duration = 250;

var lineOpacity = "0.25";
var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
var lineStroke = "1.5px";
var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

var circleOpacity = '0.85';
var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
var circleRadius = 3;
var circleRadiusHover = 6;


/* Format Data */

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) { 
  d.values.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.count = +d.count;    
  });
});

/* Scale */
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width-margin]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.count)])
  .range([height-margin, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
  .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


/* Add line into SVG */
var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.date))
  .y(d => yScale(d.count));

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'line-group')  
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .style("fill", color(i))        
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
        .attr("y", 5);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
    })
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')  
  .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
  .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
  .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll('.line')
                    .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
      d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
                    .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
        .style("cursor", "none");
    });


/* Add circles in the line */
lines.selectAll("circle-group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d => d.values).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle")  
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .text(`${d.count}`)
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.count) - 10);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .selectAll(".text").remove();
    })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.count))
  .attr("r", circleRadius)
  .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this) 
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadius);  
      });


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var extent = d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a"))
            .ticks(Math.floor(( Date.parse(extent[1]) - Date.parse(extent[0]) ) / 86400000));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(7);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .text("Total values");
```

```css
svg {
  font - family: Sans - Serif, Arial;
}

.line {
  stroke - width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path {
  stroke: black;
}

.text {
  font - size: 12 px;
}

.title - text {
  font - size: 12 px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue  but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer